# Creating multiple instances and setting property values

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, instantiation

I am accessing a .CSV file and converting the values to be displayed in a DataGrid, my problem was I only had one defined instance and it used to be outside the loop and I haven't set its properties.

*How can I create multiple instances within the loop and set the property values while I'm at it?*

CSV Format is:
'header'
'string,string,int,string' (up to 300 entries)

Here is the main code, called from clicking Menu->Open:

```
        // Function to open a .CSV file and assign the values within to a List.
    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
        // Set strings to retrieve current directory and store stocklist.csv as "filename"
        string filename = @"C:\StockFile\stocklist.csv";

        // Read all lines in file and set indexer to 0.
        string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        string[] StockDetails = new string[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < linesInFile.Length; i++)
        {
            // Load lines in file and increment by 1.
            string currentLine1 = linesInFile[i];
            // Split the current line by separator ,
            StockDetails = currentLine1.Split(',');

            Stock item = new Stock();
            stocks.Add(item);
        }
        var list = new BindingList<Stock>(stocks);
        stockGridView.DataSource = list;
    }
```

Here is my Stock class:

```
    class Stock
    {
        public string Code { get; internal set; }
        public string Desc { get; internal set; }
        public int CurCnt { get; internal set; }
        public string Order { get; internal set; }

        public Stock(string code, string desc, int curcnt, string order)
        {
            Code = code;
            Desc = desc;
            CurCnt = curcnt;
            Order = order;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you need to initialize the instance of Stock item, and every time in the loop the new keyword will create a new instance of it and adding the created instance to the list

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
        // Set strings to retrieve current directory and store stocklist.csv as "filename"
        string filename = @"C:\StockFile\stocklist.csv";

        // Read all lines in file and set indexer to 0.
        string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        string[] StockDetails = new string[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < linesInFile.Length; i++)
        {
            // Load lines in file and increment by 1.
            string currentLine1 = linesInFile[i];
            // Split the current line by separator ,
            StockDetails = currentLine1.Split(',');

        Stock item = new Stock(StockDetails[0],StockDetails[1],StockDetails[2],StockDetails[3]);
    stocks.Add(item);
        }
        var list = new BindingList<Stock>(stocks);
        stockGridView.DataSource = list;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that, the thing I was missing is so glaringly obvious now, I'm glad I can say I'm only a novice at this stuff. Haha.

Data Grid is now populated from the list perfectly (after tweaking the column names to be more than just a placeholder).